# talend studio: logs file are not generated in

Tags: talend, logfile

when i try to generate logs file in talend with the "stats and logs" option below i only get the stat file and there is no logs file or meter file

i tried to change in log4j settings and nothing changed too

is there a way to generate a log file for every job i execute in specific folder?

thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: you have to use a tlogcatcher component as you ticked the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will only have logs if

- You have generated java exception
- you have twarn or tdie components

To get data in your flowmeter file, you have to manually monitor flows in your job :
Select your flow (in my example i selected "row1" flow) , in advanced parameters, check "monitor connection". You'll then have a line in your flowmeter file regarding the number of lines in that flow.
[image]

Comment: thats so much helpful, thank you!